Realistic Anthropomorphic Hummingbird
Continuation of this question.
Would a Velociraptor style body work for anthropomorphic hummingbirds?
If not, what would anthropomorphic hummingbirds look like?
Criteria:
Must be able to use and create tools at a similar level to humans
Flight
Intelligence equal to that of a human (ignore if this will not affect your answer)
What would a realistic anthro hummingbird look like?

What is an "anthropomorphic hummingbird"? Hummingbiirds are tiny apodiform birds, anatomically pretty much as different from humans as a tetrapod can get. (And hummingbirds are only very distantly related to velociraptors; basically their only connection is that they are both theropod dinosaurs. Their most recent common ancestor lived at least 160 million years ago; that is almost one hundred million years before the extinction of the non-avian dinosaurs.)

"Anthropomorphic" means "having or exhibiting human characteristics." Specifically and exactly what human characteristics are we talking about? And what's your measure of "realistic" since no such creature exists nor can (depending on what human traits you choose)? VTC:Needs More Details, which will be revoked when the question is well defined.

The total mass of a Bee Hummingbird is roughly a thousandth of that of the mass of the average human brain. Can you clarify the question in light of that simple fact?

The smartest birds use claws and beaks to manipulate tools and stuff pretty effectively. Hummingbirds as we know them can do neither - their feet are extremely limited (compared to, say, a parrot's) and their weak flimsy beaks barely articulate since they only really need to stick their tongues out to eat from flowers or weave tiny fibers into a nest (compared to, say, a raven's). Their wings have developed to perfectly suit their size and mobility needs, so those probably need to remain unchanged. And their extremely tiny brains cannot hold a complex enough network of neurons to be capable of intelligence comparable to humans. If you make it any larger, then their already extreme dietary needs (they must eat pretty much constantly) would grow too great for their little bodies to sustain.
There's just not a realistic way to explain a hummingbird with the abilities you describe. You'd have to change their physiology substantially, to the point where they don't resemble hummingbirds at all. If you want a story about intelligent inventive hummingbirds then you're better off just giving them hands and handwaving their intelligence.
